# How to submit slider value when user change it's value, without any buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get a sphere floater to answer to my web page as soon as the user releases a slider, just as in a remote controller. However, with my little to no experience in HTML, I was not able to come up with a solution like "if slider's value changes, post new value (do what the submit button does)", as I probably could on something like C++ or Python.

Right now, my HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 250px;
    height: 10px;
  position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    left:30px;
    top:300px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

}
</style>
<body>
<h1 style="color:blue;">Floating spheres</h1>
<p>Use slider to change sphere's height.</p>

<FORM action="/" method="post">
<P>
<input type="range" name="POT" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Power: <span id="demo"></span>%</p><br>
<INPUT type="submit" name="Send">
</P>
</FORM>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I don't have much time to go deeper into HTML right now, so straight forward answers are much appreciated.

**I want to change the value of "myRange".**

Comment: "if slider's value changes, post new value (do what the submit button does)" : Can you explain further on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to POST the value from the FORM when the user releases the slider, instead of having to press the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `onmouseup` event.  This one is triggered when the user releases the mouse over your slider, meaning it is triggered when their done sliding it.  From there, you can have it run the `submit` function. I added an id attribute to the form, but you can navigate to it via relative selectors from your slider (but that is more messy).

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

slider.onmouseup = function () {
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

```css
#slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 250px;
    height: 10px;
  position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    left:30px;
    top:300px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:blue;">Floating spheres</h1>
<p>Use slider to change sphere's height.</p>

<FORM action="/" method="post" id="form">
<P>
<input type="range" name="POT" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
<p>Power: <span id="demo"></span>%</p><br>
<INPUT type="submit" name="Send">
</P>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Thanks!! That did it!